# Material Button won't cast white elevation shadow on Android 11

Tags: android, android-view, material-components-android

I have a Material Button (from Google's Material Components) which can cast black shadow normally. But when I change the shadow color, it won't appear at all. Here's the button's XML portion :

```xml
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           android:id="@+id/next"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_activity_horizontal"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:elevation="8dp"
           android:layout_margin="16dp"
           android:text="@string/setup_next"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nickname_entry_wrapper"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           tools:enabled="true"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
           android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
           android:paddingVertical="12dp"
           android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#FFFFFFFF"
           android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#FFFFFFFF"
           android:outlineProvider="background"
           android:translationZ="8dp"
           />
```

As you can see, `outlineAmbientShadowColor` and `outlineSpotShadowColor` are supposed to change the shadow color that results from elevation and Z translation, right ? I tried adding both elevation and Z translation at once but nothing works, the button still has 0 shadow.

The button is **a child view of a Constraint Layout that has a black background**. As you can see, I even tried using different values for `outlineProvider` such as `bounds` or `paddedBounds`, yet..nothing.

If anyone has experience with these outline attributes, I'd love to have this solved. The problem **isn't specific to Android 11** only, I am just saying that I am using Android 11 for testing, since those outline attributes are only available on Android versions later than Oreo.

Comment: I had to do some work with the elevation shadows since I first commented here, and it turns out that those colors have a greater effect than I'd thought. We actually can get white shadows, but a `[Material]Button`'s default `StateListAnimator` is going to cause its base elevation to be so low that the resulting shadow might look like just a line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daw3L.png. The ones on the left have the default settings, except for the bottom's black background, to make the shadow easier to spot. You can see how a brighter color can easily drown out the minimal shadow effect.

Comment: The ones on the right have `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` with their elevations at `15dp`, and the shadows are certainly noticeable there. If you need an even more pronounced effect, the `android:ambientShadowAlpha` and `android:spotShadowAlpha"` theme attributes are available, with default values of `0.039` and `0.19` respectively, and a range of `0.0` to `1.0`. Note that they are theme attributes – so you can't set them per `View` like the others – and they are set for the `Window` as a whole, so they will effect all of the shadows in a given `Activity` or `Dialog`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike M. has mentioned in the comment, those attributes don't really ***change*** the color, they just add a little 'tint'.

If you wanna use material buttons with more features, you should take a look at this library :

[Github Repo: Carbon by ZieIony](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon)

It should fulfill the required objective (casting white shadows) successfully and without issues on all Android APIs.